# problems with kernel package in Ubuntu(18.04.3 LTS)

Tags: package-management

I recently tried to install OBS for recording.After inputting sudo apt-get install obs-studio I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libavdevice57 libdc1394-22 libfdk-aac1 libluajit-5.1-2 libluajit-5.1-common
  libmbedcrypto1 libmbedtls10 libmbedx509-0 libqt5x11extras5 libsdl2-2.0-0
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-4.18.0-22-generic linux-image-4.18.0-24-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libavdevice57 libdc1394-22 libfdk-aac1 libluajit-5.1-2 libluajit-5.1-common
  libmbedcrypto1 libmbedtls10 libmbedx509-0 libqt5x11extras5 libsdl2-2.0-0
  obs-studio
0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/4.822 kB of archives.
After this operation, 56,3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 216936 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-4.18.0-22-generic (4.18.0-22.23~18.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-22-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 38: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.18.0-22-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-4.18.0-22-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-4.18.0-24-generic (4.18.0-24.25~18.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-24-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 38: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.18.0-24-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-4.18.0-24-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.18.0-22-generic
 linux-image-4.18.0-24-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It seems like there's something wrong with the packages linux-image-4.18.0-22-generic and linux-image-4.18.0-24-generic. I tried a few methods to get this fixed,including:

$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade and
$ sudo apt-get autoremove --purge

but neither worked,an the problem continues to happen.

I'd appreciate if anyone suggest another solution.

EDIT:I tried to change the usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig file,but

```
prefix="/usr"
exec_prefix="/usr"
sbindir="${exec_prefix}/sbin"
bindir="${exec_prefix}/bin"
sysconfdir="/etc"
PACKAGE_NAME=GRUB
PACKAGE_VERSION=2.02-2ubuntu8.13
host_os=linux-gnu
datadir="${datarootdir}"
if [ "x$pkgdatadir" = x ]; then
    pkgdatadir="${datadir}/grub"
fi
# export it for scripts
export pkgdatadir

grub_cfg=""
grub_mkconfig_dir="${sysconfdir}"/grub.d

self=`basename $0`
```

line 38( the one between export `pkgdatardir` and `grub_cfg=""`) appears to be empty,and I can't spot the syntax error in the code

EDIT 2:The mistake could be on `etc/default/grub`,however,said file only has exactly 37 lines:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1



# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

FINAL EDIT:changing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1`
to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1"
```

worked perfectly.Thanks for the answears!

Comment: Please show line 38 of */etc/default/grub* by adding output of `awk 'NR==38 {print}' /etc/default/grub` command to the question. And to get all info - add contents of whole `/etc/default/grub` file.

Comment: added it to the post,but the command doesn't output anything,since the file only has 37 lines.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add closing quote to the end of first line.

You need to change it from

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1"
```

then comment out second `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line and
then run `sudo update-grub` manually.

Comment: There is a second line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` further down in the file, this will take precedence over the first line. That should be fixed as well.